# Knex.js verifying query results in server side code

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I have a function that is supposed to check if a license plate already exists in my MySQL database, but on the then-promise-return the result comes as: 
**result: [object Object]**. How do you actually get the response of this knex query and parse it to check for a license plate existing?

```
var licensePlateExists = function(licensePlate){
  knex.select('plate').from('licensePlates').where({'plate': licensePlate}).limit(1).then(function(result){
    console.log("Result: " + result);
    if(!result){
      return true;
    } 
    return false;
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

I think I might have an error related to the query itself, but I tested the raw query string in MySQL CLI and it outputs the row as expected. Maybe ordering matters in the knex query builder?

P.S. This doesn't error, it executes all the way through.

Comment: how are you consuming this function? also, a sample output from that console.log would help us to understand better what is happening.

Comment: Okay so it returned: `result: [object Object]` . Try to log this with `console.dir(result);` or do `var stringResult = JSON.stringify(result);`

Comment: Trying these  console.dir(result); [ { plate: 'VDS-1111-MA' } ] and console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
[{"plate":"VDS-1111-MA"}]

Comment: Awesome so this does work.

Comment: Yeah, seems like it :) If it is empty or any other falsy value then you know that plate does not exist in your db.

Comment: Yea! So I think the main trick is it always returns a collection even with limit(1) or if it just returns 1 item, so the accessing the actual licensePlate json object requires result[0]

Comment: I mean you can always optimize your queries. `select count(1)
from table
where key = value;` This should return 0 or 1 as a result. "0" indicates "not exists" and "1" indicates "exists".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
knex.select('plate').from('licensePlates').where('plate', licensePlate)
```

Actually using count query would be better